# Route LAN traffic through eth0, not tun0, on my VPN access point

Tags: networking, vpn, routing, iptables, wireless-access-point

How can I make my Access Point send traffic to `192.168.1.0` through `eth0` and all other traffic through `tun0`?

I have set up a Raspberry Pi VPN access point. It sits on the same subnet as all my servers, `192.168.1.0` and is, as are the servers, connected by cable to my modem/router.
The Raspberry Pi then has a WIFI stick (`wlan0`) for clients to connect to, it runs its own subnet `192.168.2.0` and uses `iptables` rules to forward all traffic from its clients on `wlan0` through my VPN connection (`tun0`).

I set up this forward by doing;

```
sudo iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o tun0 -j MASQUERADE
sudo iptables -A FORWARD -i tun0 -o wlan0 -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
sudo iptables -A FORWARD -i wlan0 -o tun0 -j ACCEPT
```

My problem is that now a client connected by wifi to my access point cannot communicate with my servers. How can I achieve this?

```
|                                            |       ¦
|                          __________________|_______¦_________
|                          |      Modem/Router/DCHP server    |
|                          |             192.168.1.254        |
|                          |_________________________¦________|
|                                            |       ¦
|                                            |       ¦
|                                  __________________¦_
|                                  |  8-port switch  ¦ |
|                                  |_________________¦_|
|                                    |             | ¦    
|                                    |             | -----------
|                ____________________|             |__________ ¦
|                |                                       eth0| ¦tun0
|        __________________                        ________________________
|        |    Server      |                        |  Pi VPN Access Point |
|        |  192.168.1.79  |                        |  eth0: 192.168.1.81  |
|        |________________|                        |  tun0: 10.X.X.X      |
|                                                  |  wlan0:192.168.2.1   |
|                                                  |______________________|
|                                                       |wlan0
|                                                       | 
|                                             __________|___________
|                                             |   Laptop           |
|                                             | wlan0: 192.168.2.2 |
|                                             |____________________|
```

I have described my Access Point setup more in detail at; http://www.snabela.net/index.php/2013/11/raspberry-vpn-access-point/

What do I need to do to be able to ssh from Laptop to Server whilst all Internet traffic from the AP's clients is sent through the VPN? Can I add another iptables rule?

The Access Points ifconfig -a output:

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr b8:28:eb:f1:77:93  
          inet addr:192.168.1.81  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:124292 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:86097 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:136739836 (130.4 MiB)  TX bytes:15199088 (14.4 MiB)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:16436  Metric:1
          RX packets:60 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:60 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:6200 (6.0 KiB)  TX bytes:6200 (6.0 KiB)

mon.wlan0 Link encap:UNSPEC  HWaddr F8-1B-67-20-B3-61-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00  
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:4760 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:630721 (615.9 KiB)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)

tun0      Link encap:UNSPEC  HWaddr 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00  
          inet addr:10.4.43.179  P-t-P:10.4.43.178  Mask:255.255.255.255
          UP POINTOPOINT RUNNING NOARP MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:108875 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:75807 errors:0 dropped:29 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:100 
          RX bytes:126611820 (120.7 MiB)  TX bytes:6303503 (6.0 MiB)

wlan0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr f8:1b:67:20:b3:61  
          inet addr:192.168.2.1  Bcast:192.168.2.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:75019 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:109376 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:7219164 (6.8 MiB)  TX bytes:130045181 (124.0 MiB)
```

The Access Point's route -n output:

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         10.4.43.178     128.0.0.0       UG    0      0        0 tun0
0.0.0.0         192.168.1.254   0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth0
10.4.0.1        10.4.43.178     255.255.255.255 UGH   0      0        0 tun0
10.4.43.178     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.255 UH    0      0        0 tun0
95.211.191.34   192.168.1.254   255.255.255.255 UGH   0      0        0 eth0
128.0.0.0       10.4.43.178     128.0.0.0       UG    0      0        0 tun0
192.168.1.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth0
192.168.2.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 wlan0
```

Answer (score 0):

I'll hazard a guess and say that your default FORWARD policy is to REJECT or DROP (check with `iptables -L FORWARD`). If that's correct, your entire problem is this line:

```
sudo iptables -A FORWARD -i wlan0 -o tun0 -j ACCEPT
```

What it does is to ACCEPT for FORWARDing anything that comes in through `wlan0` and would go out through `tun0`. Which does not match a packet from `192.168.2.2` to `192.168.1.79`, because that would go out through `eth0`.

The easiest thing to do is to remove that line and replace it with these two, to allow forwarding of everything in either direction between your internal interfaces:

```
sudo iptables -A FORWARD -i wlan0 -j ACCEPT
sudo iptables -A FORWARD -i eth0 -j ACCEPT
```

If you simply wish to exclude your server from the VPN, add `-o wlan0` to the second line. Of course, if you want to add more, stricter requirements, such as session establishment having to go in a particular direction or whatever, these rules are the ones that need to be adjusted. Have fun, and keep a console handy. ;-)